# Applying multiple CSS styling options when using pandas.style.apply

Tags: css, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I am building my own legend for a complicated figure where some lines have a hexadecimal color (e.g. `#009933`). To build the legend I have a column `'color'` that has the same hexadecimal color as the line in the plot. I apply the color to the background of the color cell using the pandas apply function, as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd

def legend_styling(val):
    if val.name == 'color':
        return ['background-color: %s'%x for x in val]
    elif val.name == 'shift':
        return ['font-weight: bold' for x in val]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'form': {1: 'C4H6O5', 2: 'C4H6O5', 3: 'C4H4O4', 4: 'C4H5N3O'}, 
    'name': {1: 'Malate', 2: '3-Dehydro-L-threonate', 3: 'Fumarate', 4: 'Cytosine'}, 
    'color': {1: '#009933', 2: '#009933', 3: '#e67300', 4: '#e63900'},
    'shift': {1: 'm+0', 2: 'm+0', 3: 'm+0', 4: 'm+0'}
})
df.style.apply(legend_styling, axis=0,subset=['color','shift'])
```

[image: output]

I would like to color the text (the black hex codes) in the `'color'` column the same as the background so that they blend away. I somehow need to apply both of the following CSS styling options to the cell `'background-color: #xxxxxx'` and `'color: #xxxxxx'`. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you were able to resolve this, but I thought I would share my solution for anyone who might chance upon this page. I like to take a more readable approach when applying styles:

```
def style_conditions(x):
    bg_color_na = '#d9d9d9'
    bg_color_1 = '#ff0000'
    bg_color_2 = '#ffc000'
    bg_color_3 = '#ffff00'
    bg_color_4 = '#00b0f0'
    color_1 = '#ffffff'
    
    
    if x == 'Not Inspected':
        return  f'background-color: {bg_color_na}'
    elif x == '1-Urgent Repair':
        return  f'background-color: {bg_color_1}; color: {color_1}'
    elif x == '2-Repair Within a Week':
        return  f'background-color: {bg_color_2}'
    elif x == '3-Repair Next Opportunity':
        return  f'background-color: {bg_color_3}'
    elif x == '4-Scheduled Repair':
        return  f'background-color: {bg_color_4}'
    else:
        return ''

df.style.applymap(style_conditions)
```

Here note x == '1-Urgent Repair' gets two styles:

1. One for 'background-color' to shade the cell
2. One for 'color' to change the text color to white.

So, to answer your question more directly, to apply multiple styles just separate by semi-colon.